# how to lock files and make it read-only in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am using VisualSVN Server to store my files in a repository. Then I check them out using TortoiseSVN client. I want to make sure that when one client has locked and started working on a file, the other clients should not be able to make changes to the same file as well. When they check out the repository they should see the file as "read-only".

In order to do this I went to the config file of the TortoiseSVN and added the property `"*.* = svn:needs-lock=true"` and I also uncommented the line `enable-auto-props = yes`, both in the server and the client side to be sure. But still after making the lock, the other clients are able to modify the file, though they cannot commit it, since the lock is already made.

Can anyone please take a look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you want to do is not how Subversion works. Locking should only be needed for binary files, and then it should be understood that you *first* try and get a lock before editing.

Comment: If you think that you need to enforce locking on every file in the whole repository, you're either managing your project wrong, or [Subversion isn't the right tool for your needs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.copy-merge.sb-1).

Answer (score 1):

Auto-props instructs Subversion to automatically set properties on **newly added or imported** files. It won't touch files that already exist in a repository. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts

To implement the lock-modify-unlock model you are required to perform the following general steps:

1. The first step would be to set `svn:needs-lock` property on files. After applying `svn:needs-lock` to a file the file gets read-only attribute. Before editing the file, it should be explicitly locked (this fact is reflected in the repository). After committing the lock is released by default.
2. Then you can implement some kind of locking policy (see
   http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html#svn.advanced.locking.break-steal)
   to restrict some of the users from being able to steal locks,
3. You can setup pre- and -post lock and unlock hooks to notify
   users (or managers) that a file has been locked or unlocked, when and
   by whom.

I strongly advise you to carefully read the following SVNBook sections:

- [SVNBook | The lock-modify-unlock solution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.lock-unlock)
- [SVNBook | Locking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html)

Comment: It should also be noted that auto-props are a *client* feature and as such cannot be relied upon for all cases. You can't assume that all of your users will have their client(s) configured exactly the way you want them.

Comment: @alroc Some kind of AD group policy can be used to deploy svn runtime configuration to clients automatically via Windows Registry.

Comment: Unless you have a client which doesn't respect the SVN standard configurations. Or have an outside contractor who isn't on your domain. Or a user who fiddles with his config files. There are still ways for that to break down.

Answer (score 0):

With the JIRA add-on called [Commit Policy](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.jira-commit-policy-plugin/server/overview) you can **reject modified files that do not match a regex or glob expression**:

> "Changed files must match a pattern" condition
>
> Verifies the committed files, including modified, added, removed or otherwise touched files.
>
> It matches a regular expression or a glob pattern to the every file included in the commit. The condition is satisfied only if the pattern matches all file paths.

With this condition type, you can lock single or multiple files (glob):

```
!({*/README.txt,README.txt})
```

...single or multiple directories (glob):

```
!(src/main/java/com/company/internal/)
```

or any mix of these.

See more examples [here](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-commit-policy-plugin/documentation/best-practices).